# How do can i storing string in char*s[] in C?

Tags: c

I am attempting to store a string in a variable declared as `char *name[2];`. I am using `scanf()` to obtain the value from user input. This is my code so far and its currently not working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{   char *name[2];
    scanf("%s",name[0]);
    printf("%s",name[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c

Answer (score 2):

You haven't allocated any storage for the actual strings - `char *name[2]` is just an array of two uninitialised pointers. Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char name[2][80];
    scanf("%s", name[0]);
    printf("%s", name[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

or, if it really does need to be `char *name[2]`, then you can allocate memory dynamically:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *name[2];
    name[0] = malloc(80);  // allocate memory for name[0] (NB: name[1] left uninitialised)
    scanf("%s", name[0]);
    printf("%s", name[0]);
    free(name[0]);         // free memory allocated for name[0]
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char *name[2];
```

You have 2 pointers which are of type `char`

Allocate memory to the pointer using `malloc()` or any of its family membres.

```
name[0] = malloc(20);
```